# Inserting data into server database with PHP from client JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, security, insert, mariadb

I have this function I wrote to insert a record into a database on my server from a webpage using JavaScript. The php program is using prepared statements to update the mariaDB.  Is there any danger here with this code? Any improvements I could make? The code works fine and I have no issues.  I was wondering if there is something I could do to improve security.

```
 function insertRecord() {
    const todayWork = new Date();
    const dateInsert = todayWork.getFullYear() + '-' + (todayWork.getMonth() + 1).toString().padStart(2, '0') + '-' + todayWork.getDate().toString().padStart(2, '0');
    const data1 = dateInsert;
    const data2 = state.pointCount;
    const data3 = 1;
    const data4 = wgstats.totalGamesPlayed;
    const data5 = wgstats.consecutiveWins;
    const data6 = wgstats.longestStreak;
    const data7 = wgstats.totalPointsAwarded;
    const data8 = state.hintCount;
    const data9 = 'Y';

    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', 'insertgameresults.php', true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && xhr.status === 200) {
            console.log('Data inserted successfully');
        }
    };
    xhr.send('dataOne=' + data1 + '&dataTwo=' + data2 + '&dataThree=' + data3 + '&dataFour=' + data4 + '&dataFive=' + data5 + '&dataSix=' + data6 + '&dataSeven=' + data7 + '&dataEight=' + data8 + '&dataNine=' + data9);
}
```

Comment: You can use FormData(), some js validation i.e. yup https://github.com/jquense/yup. We have 2023, use fetch instead of XMLHttpRequest ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your sending of data is good and no problem as long as it is working and instead focus on your PHP(backend) and make sure that data has every validations(e.g mysqli_real_escape_string) there is. Make sure that every data before inserting to your database is what your database expected to be received.

Comment: Should i be checking to make sure the data is as expected.  LIke data9 I am expecting a 'Y' or a ' '.  If not one of those characters reject the insert?  Also make sure other parameters are within the expected values?  Like data2 should be between 0 and 5.  If not reject record?

Comment: Yes, I know it's a bit skeptical since you put the value yourself but it is a great practice to make sure that every data in your database is what your database expect it to received.

Yes, make sure that if your database is expecting to receive int value of between 0 and 5, make sure that you validate the data if it is in the range of value